# How to convert a 2D array to 1D array with the value as the index?

Tags: java

I have a 2D array that gets dynamically created by any integer N. Initially, I need to set all values in the array to a value that represents it being "uninitialized" where I use the number "-1". However, I want to convert this 2D array to a 1D array and assign every value to be equal to its index in the new 1D array.

```
public class Percolation {

private int[][] id;
private int[] array1D;
private int blocked = -1;   //a number that doesn't exist in the array

// create N-by-N grid, with all sites blocked
public Percolation(int N){

    id = new int[N][N];
    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
    { for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) id[k][i] = blocked; } 
}


// open site (row i, column j) if it is not already
public void open(int i, int j){


}
```

In the open method it should change the value at the given indexes to be the corresponding index in a 1D array. For example:

> [-1] [-1]
>
> [-1] [-1]

Would then become:

> [0] [1] [2] [3]

Unfortunately, since this is homework I'm unsure how I can share the grid size "N" to be able to create a new 1D array with the indexes as the values.

Comment: Concerning your last paragraph: You get the grid size `N` in your class with `id.length`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the grid size `N` in your class with `id.length`.

Comment: I can't believe it was so simple! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure if this helps answer your question but the following algorithm is for indexing a one dimensional matrix that represents a two dimensional matrix:

```
colSize*row+col
```

where colSize is the max number of columns.

For example the following matrix:

```
 [0, 1, 2, 3;
  4, 5, 6, 7;
  8, 9, 10, 11]
```

so to access row 1 col 3 (ie 6 which is the index number can be found by:

```
3*1+3 = 6;
```

So you should be able to fill out your 1D matrix with just the number of columns and rows using this formula.

Comment: Thanks Ben. I knew that much, but my problem was getting the grid size as halex mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You could also have done something like that, considering N is a given parameter to your constructor:

```
public class Percolation {
     private int size;
     //...

    public Percolation(int N){
         size = N;
         //...    
    }
}
```

The scope of the variable is all your class. If you set it public, you could also access it with p.size, where p is an instance of Percolation